# SQL script for menu structure

Tags: sql, menu

I want to create menu structure from a database.

For example, the database is the following:

```
id   name     parent

1     x         null

2     y         1

3     z         null

4     a         3

5     b         2
```

The result should be:

```
-x

--y

---b

-z

--a
```

Now, the algorithm I have on mind is the following:
1. first find a column which has 'parent' = null. (I'll call this column A)
2. then find a column which has 'parent' = A's parent. (I'll call this column B)
3. then find a column which has 'parent' = B's parent.
etc.

```
WHILE (SELECT MenuText FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE parent = NULL)
BEGIN
   SELECT MenuText FROM dbo.Table2 WHERE parent = ...
END
```

Is it good?

Comment: What RDBMS/version are you using?

Comment: You should look into CTEs (Common Table Expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a candidate for a [tree query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034153/sql-server-tree-query) (I don't know whether the Express Edition supports this, though).